# Create an instance of generic Type

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
ModelBuilder builder = new ModelBuilder();
builder.Entity<Model>().Add(new ModelMapper());
```

Instead I would like to use it as follows:

```
ModelBuilder builder = new ModelBuilder();
builder.Add<ModelMapper>();
```

So the ModelBuilder Add extension would create a new instance of T and add it to builder.Entity().Add(new T);

How can I do this?

Comment: How does `ModelMapper` relate to `Model` and where is `Model` in the second code block??

Comment: ModelMapper is a class as follows: class ModelMapper : EntityMapper <T>. Does this help?

Comment: You mean `class ModelMapper : EntityMapper<Model>` ?

Comment: Yes, it is class ModelMapper : EntityMapper< Model>

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job using a combination of type constraints. You may want to make this an extension method.

```
public void Add<TEntity, TMapper>() 
    where TEntity : class
    where TMapper : EntityMapper<TEntity>, new()
{
    this.Entity<TEntity>().Add(new TMapper());
}
```

And use it like this:

```
builder.Add<Model, ModelMapper>();
```